# Object to class

Tags: java

How can I transfer object of class C to class A and B. but I cannot use constructor

I mean:

```
public class JDBC { 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        C q = new C();
        A a = new A(args, q);
        B w = new B(args, q);
        a.start();
        w.start();
    }
}
```

This variant with constructor

Comment: Use setter method and inside it validate for for null C object before calling start() method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a setter in the class A and call it passing the instance of C

```
a.setC(q);
```